# How to set DGV for editing ? Something is overriding read only = false

Tags: vb.net

I have an 11 column DGV1 on the left side of my desktop app. Two columns are set to visable = false. To the right is another 5 column DGV2. DGV1 is loaded from a CSV txt file with many unused columns using Microsoft's TextFieldParser. No cells are editable in DGV1 even though all columns are set to read only = false. DGV2 is similar, however the parsing results are saved to a CSV txt file and then loaded to the DGV2 without parsing. Where as DGV1 is loaded directly from the parsing. DGV2 edits all cells with no problem.   How can I make DGV1 editable without saving to a CSV txt file and then loading from the file.

Comment: The obvious answer is that you set `ReadOnly` to `True` for the grid itself.  That's only a guess because you haven't told us what you have done, but it seems the obvious first port of call.

Comment: Thanks for causing me to look further. Even though the columns are set to read only = false. I learned that the RowTemplate overrides everything...it was set to read only = true. Changed it to false and now everything is fine. Thanks again.